# c# асинхронное выполнение с return

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, зависает форма при обрабатывании button_click,
ранее, с этим справлялся так

```
private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    await MakePhoto();

} 

public Task MakePhoto()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //действия
    });
}
```

И форма не зависала, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать для функции

```
public string post_zapros_update(string url, string data)
{
    return html;
}
```

Чтобы форма не зависала и возвращало значение html?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    GetZapros(url_get);
    post_zapros(url_login, data);
    post_zapros_update(update_url, update_data);
    и т.д.
}
```

Между этими функциями еще вывожу результат в **richtextbox.Text = html;** и после этого делаю Update();
Как правильно сделать чтобы форма не зависала и выводила сообщение в richtextbox?

Спасибо большое...

Comment: очевидно надо использовать те же async/await внутри вызываемых функций

Comment: А почему функция `post_zapros_update` не асинхронная? Дайте её настоящий код, или переделайте её в `async`-функцию сами.

Comment: (И не `zapros`, а `query`.)

Comment: @VladD. тут скорее `request` тогда уж :)

Comment: @Grundy: Или так :)